# Is is possible to get a mismatch in envelope status counts when calculated via docusign API call?

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to generate a customized report from docusign APIs via API Envelope list status , but the counts I am getting via API doesn't match with the one we get from DocuSign console, Specially with the Voided status count, its massively different. Is it possible to have a difference. I have some responses from DocuSign supporting this.

Answer (score 0):

You can see what API calls are made by the DocuSign web app if you want.
To do that, you go click "My Preferences" from the top-right menu and then the "Enable Logging" button. Navigate back to the portal to see the totals calculated and then back to My Preferences to see the logs and download them (ZIP files).
I'm not sure what is the reason, one option - user vs. account. The totals you see in the web app are for the logged in user, not the entire account.